# Javascript new date() conversion

Tags: javascript, date, datetimepicker

Im having some troubles with conversion. It says **invalid date** when `alert(first_date) and alert(end_date)`,etc :s Im using datetimepicker to get the dates.

```
$( "#start_date" ).datetimepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            defaultDateTime: "+1w",
            showSecond: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onClose: function( selectedDateTime ) {
                $( "#end_date" ).datetimepicker( "option", selectedDateTime );
            }
        });
        $( "#end_date" ).datetimepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            defaultDateTime: "+1w",
            showSecond: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onClose: function( selectedDateTime ) {
                $( "#start_date" ).datetimepicker( "option", selectedDateTime );
            }
        });
```

Now, I need to do something like this:

```
var first_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
var last_date = new Date($('#end_date').val());
var nDifference = (last_date - first_date);
var one_day = 1000*60*60*24;
var days = Math.round(nDifference/one_day);

<input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" value=""/>
```

Comment: what is the value of `$('#start_date').val()` when you are creating the `new Date`?

Comment: if you put a `T` instead of the space, it will work - so: `2012-01-01T06:16:16` and you might or might not need a `Z` at the end, which accounts for timezone offset.

Comment: You appear to be using a jQuery plugin - [**datetimepicker**](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). Yet you are making use of the `onClose` event which is an event available only in the jQuery datepicker but not in the plugin's datetimepicker options.

Comment: @Bruno yes, im using jQuery.

Comment: @skdnewbie [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) is a plugin whereas [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is part of jQueryUI. Can you check the link and tell me if you are using that plugin and if not which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript date reliably accepts ISO date formats...

```
d = '2012-01-01 06:16:16'

console.log(new Date(d)) // invalid
console.log(new Date(d.replace(' ','T'))) // valid!
// Z at the end accounts for local timezone offset
console.log(new Date(d.replace(' ','T')+'Z'))
```